# find all documents from mongodb collection with some attribute having value lie in an array

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I want to find all documents in a collection where they have property like
Creator and i have an array which contains different values for this creator property and i want to of those documents where these different values in that array are the value of property creator in the document.

I tried by mapping the array and for each array value i tired to find document.
But due to its asynchronous nature i have to promise.all in order get that array of documents.
But when i passed that array to my react app from backend
It is showing error of incorrect react child class.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using the **$in** operator from Mongo:

```
db.customers.find({creator: {$in: ["faizulhassan.a@caratlane.com", "sajid.s@caratlane.com"]}})
```

Where **Customer** is your **collection** name.
Hope this helps..

Comment: thanks, it works same as i did by maping. But when I passed the array to frontend in react it is giving an error.

react.development.js:1061 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {posts, followings, followers, _id, name, email, password, created, __v}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: - Reacts says that you had passed array of objects to the view to render and not just array. 
- Make sure you are passing an array to be rendered in the view.

- If it an array of objects then point the key from the object to render it in the view..

Assume your array of object to be **[{name:'faizul'},{name:'hassan'}]**, say react to render the key named name..

_Within view make use of map function to loop within the array.._

`let response =  [{name:'faizul'},{name:'hassan'}];


response.map((o,i)=>{
  return(
   <div>{o.name}</div>
 )
})`

Comment: i have solved this problem, i am rendering the object in react thats why this error is showing

Comment: I am glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const answer = collectionName.find({creator: "what you want to find"});

if(!answer){
#do something
} else{
#do something
}
```